# Reaching for the values of variables of a list

Tags: c++, list, dynamic

I need to add values of variables in a linked list. I can reach certain value but can't add 2 values to a sum.

Let's assume I have two subjects, the first with 20 points and the second with 10 points.

```
struct subject {
    int points;
    subject *next;
    subject();
};

// testCounter = 2

void list::test(int points, int testCounter) {
    subject *test = new subject;
    int sum = 0, counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i <= testCounter;i++,counter++) {
        sum += points;      // maybe "test->points = points" ??
        test = test->next;
    }
    cout << "\nCounter: " << couter;   // here I get 2 like I want. 
    cout << "\nSum: " << sum; 
}
```

In the "sum" I get 10, the second value, not 30 like I would get after adding both values. Why?

Comment: Do the `subject` constructor initialize the `next` pointer? To what? Not that you seem to be using the list anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's: points
notice that you never change it so let's assume you have 2 elements in the list "test"
so

```
void list::test(int points, int testCounter) {
    subject *test = new subject;//
```

^here your create an entire new list and that one has 1 element and it's point value was never initialized

```
    int sum = 0, counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i <= testCounter;i++,counter++) {
```

^when dealing with lists always check if you're not accessing a null "chain"

```
        sum += points;      // maybe "test->points = points" ?? <-
```

more like sum += test->points;

```
        test = test->next;
    }
    cout << "\nCounter: " << couter;   // here I get 2 like I want. 
    cout << "\nSum: " << sum; 
}
```

so let's rewrite it:

a) assume this:

```
subject *mylist = new subject; // you can make a constructor for an element instead of what i'm going to do

mylist->points  = 10;
mylist->next = new subject;
(mylist->next)->points = 20;
(mylist->next)->next = nullptr; //super important remember in c and c++ there's no default value it contain garbage - meaning illegal address
```

^now we basicly have mylist as a list of two elements that ends on the last
so we'll write a function that gets a list and gets x as number of elements to print

```
void printXElementsInList(const subject *mylist, int x)
{
   int counter = 0, sum = 0;
   while (mylist && counter < x) /*try to make the same thing without mylist and 3 
  instead with the same list, without inserting nullptr it will print 2 and 30 
 cause that's what we have otherwise it will throw an exception!*/
   {
      sum += mylist->points;  //here i'm accessing the points value inside the each chain in the linked list
      mylist = mylist->next; 
      ++counter;
   }
   cout << "counter: " << counter << "\nsum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

notice the way i've created the list is abit ugly but the function is what matters to your question and not how to properly create a list :) hf and hope everything is clearer now

Comment: oh i forgot to write how to use this: use this like that:   printXElementsInList(mylist , 3);